# An implementation for the double factorial

Tags: python, python-2.x, recursion, iteration

I have written this piece of code that implements the double factorial in Python both iteratively and recursively; the code works without problems, but I'm interested in improving my overall programming style. Here's the code:

```
def semif_r(n):                 #recursive implementation
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        z = 1
    else:
        z= n * semif_r(n-2)
    return z


def semif_i(n):             #iterative implementation
    N = 1
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n%2 == 1:
        for i in range(0,n/2):
            N =  (2*i + 1)*N
            VAL = N
        return n*VAL

    elif n%2 == 0:
        for i in range(0,n/2):
            N =  (2*i+2)*N
            VAL = N
    return VAL
```

I hope that some experienced programmers can give me some feedback about improving my code!

Comment: On my machine the recursive code works 'without problems' until `n = 1998`, at which point I get: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: Yep, importing the sys package and changing the maximum recursions will solve this

Comment: It won't solve it, but you could mitigate problems up to a point. There is still a maximum limit. What I'm saying is the two implementations have different behaviour in the face of limited resources. You might want to create a `ValueError`, and document it in the function's docstring.

Answer (score 4):

#### The recursive solution

The `z` local variable, you can just return directly.

The `else` could be dropped, as the `if` before it returns from the function.

Adding some doctests would be useful.

```
def semif_r(n):
    """
    >>> semif_r(5)
    15
    >>> semif_r(6)
    48
    >>> semif_r(25)
    7905853580625
    """
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * semif_r(n - 2)
```

#### The iterative solution

No need to declare `N` up front. You could declare and initialize when you need it.

`VAL` is unnecessary, whenever its value is referenced, it's equal to `N`, so you could use `N` instead of `VAL` everywhere.

The start value of a range is 0 by default, so you don't need to specify that explicitly.

In `n / 2`, you're counting on that integer division will occur with truncation. In Python 3 there is a separate operator `//` for this.
It's good to make your code ready for Python 3, by using `//`, and adding this import:

```
from __future__ import division
```

The logic in the two range loops are almost the same. It would be good to extract that logic to a helper function.

As with the recursive implementation, doctests would be nice.

---

Note that in this code:

> ```
> elif n%2 == 1:
>     # ...
>
> elif n%2 == 0:
>     # ...
> ```

There, the 2nd `elif` could be replaced with a simple `else`,
since if `n % 2 != 1`, then it must be inevitably 0.

---

Putting it all together:

```
def semif_i(n):  
    """
    >>> semif_i(5)
    15
    >>> semif_i(6)
    48
    >>> semif_i(25)
    7905853580625
    """
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1

    def multiply(coef):
        val = 1
        for i in range(n // 2):
            val *= (2 * i + coef)
        return val

    if n % 2 == 1:
        return n * multiply(1)

    return multiply(2)
```

#### Coding style

Please follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the coding style guide (see the writing style in my sample implementations).

Answer (score 4):

**Simplify Simplify Simplify**

[`janos`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111439/31292) covered the recursive case well enough, but the iterative case can be greatly reduced by simply using the same approach as your recursive algorithm. What I mean is, your recursive implementation performs `N * (N-2) * (N-4) * ...`, but your iterative implementation involves looping in the other direction, and then performing some extra math to boot. Rather than iterating up to `N // 2`, simply count by twos from the top down. `range(N, 1, -2)` will give you everything you want:

```
>>> range(1, 1, -2)
[]
>>> range(2, 1, -2)
[2]
>>> range(15, 1, -2)
[15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3]
```

So you could simply write your loop around that (remembering the caveat that `range` returns a full list, whereas `xrange` gives you the elements on demand):

```
def semif_i(n): 
    product = 1
    for i in xrange(n, 1, -2):
        product *= i
    return product
```

This can be reduced further using [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), but YMMV on whether or not this is any better:

```
def semif_i(n):
    return reduce(operator.mul,
        xrange(n, 1, -2),
        1)
```

Either way, I prefer this approach since you don't actually need a special case for `n=0` or `n=1`. `xrange()` implicitly takes care of this for you by simply providing an empty range!